# Why is script.js in localhost different from the script.js in the root directory

Tags: java, html, localhost, web-development-server

I'm setting up a localhost server and I have 2 files in the root directory, script.js and padding.html. The html file directly references the script.js file. when i set up the localhost site with `php -S localhost:8000 padding.html`, the content of the script.js file becomes the content of the padding.html file.

I've tried re-saving my work in my code editor, resetting the server and reloading the page.

script.js

```
function getValue (id) {
    text = document.getElementById(id).value; //value of the text input
    alert(text);
    return false;
}
```

padding.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>javatest</title>
    <script src = script.js></script>
    <body>
        <div class="entry foreground-color">
            <form onsubmit="return getValue('commands')">
                <input type="text" name="commands" size="60"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

run the server then go to inspect element then the console, and an error comes up saying `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`
clicking on it then brings you to the 'script.js' file, which is just a copy of the padding.html file with a different name. This file should be the script.js file shown above

Comment: I always start the PHP server with `php -S localhost:8080 -t .`. Here, I'm specifying that the web root is the current folder `.`. The server software then looks for `index.php` or `index.html` for the root document.

Answer (score 0):

In padding.html, you appear to have a syntax error that would cause that to appear in the console. Replace `<script src = script.js></script>` with `<script src="script.js"></script>` (note the added quotation marks).